# Append data to nested object in logstash config

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, logstash

how to add data to nested object from other select statement?

Now i have a code (**`Select dataA FROM tableA`**):

```
filter {
    if [type] == "tableA" {
      json {
        source => "permissions"
        target => "permissionsNested"
        remove_field=>["permissions"]
      }
    }
}
```

How to add data from **`Select dataB FROM tableB`** by id for type tableA?

This is needed because i have dataB as many-to-many relational.